# Sum array of vectors by one of fields - scala

Tags: scala, vector, mahout

I have an array of vectors in scala:

```
import org.apache.mahout.math.{ VectorWritable, Vector, DenseVector }
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.dirichlet.UncommonDistributions

     val data = new ArrayBuffer[Vector]()
     for (i <- 100 to num) {
      data += new DenseVector(Array[Double](

      i % 30,  

      UncommonDistributions.rNorm(100, 100),

      UncommonDistributions.rNorm(100, 100)
      )



 }
```

Lets say I want to sum second and third fields grouping by first row.

What is the better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use groupBy function on list, and then map each group - simply in one line of code:

```
 data groupBy (_(0)) map { case (k,v) => k -> (v map (_(2)) sum) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the **groupBy** method present in Collections:

[http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector@groupBy[K](f:A=>K):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr]](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector@groupBy%5BK%5D%28f%3aA=%3EK%29%3ascala.collection.immutable.Map%5BK,Repr%5D)

This will create a Map of Vectors base on a discriminator you specify.

Edit: Some code example:

```
// I created a different Array of Vector as I don't have Mahout dependencies
// But the output is similar
// A List of Vectors with 3 values inside
val num = 100
val data = (0 to num).toList.map(n => {
  Vector(n % 30, n / 100, n * 100)
})

// The groupBy will create a Map of Vectors where the Key is the result of the function
// And here, the function return the first value of the Vector
val group = data.groupBy(v => { v.apply(0) })

// Also a subset of the result:
// group:
// scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]]] = Map(0 -> List(Vector(0, 0, 0), Vector(0, 0, 3000), Vector(0, 0, 6000), Vector(0, 0, 9000)), 5 -> List(Vector(5, 0, 500), Vector(5, 0, 3500), Vector(5, 0, 6500), Vector(5, 0, 9500)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but Now, how will I sum that?

Comment: You will need to fold each values of the Map into a single Vector with the second and third values summed up. The goal is to have then a Map of [Double, Vector]. If you don't mind I will let you try by yourself and propose an example of it only if you don't succeed

Comment: this was my result for summing and sorting desc - 
 `group.mapValues(_.foldLeft(0)(_+_(2))).toList.sortBy{-_._2}`
have you something better?

Comment: yes, but all the solution seems a bit clumsy - convert into map then map values then sum them then convert into list then sort...
isn't a shorter solution?

Comment: Well, there is a `sum` method in Collections that would come in handy. But then you would need to drastically change the format of your input to use it (Using probably Tuple instead of Vectors). Which is probably not what you want to do.